# IndexOutOfBoundsException at Index: 4, Size: 4 when adding elements to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at seatOrganiser.Arranger.breakIfTwo(Arranger.java:30)
    at seatOrganiser.Arranger.main(Arranger.java:17)
```

When I click on the `ArrayList.java:653` or `ArrayList.java:429`, I get a "653 is not a valid line number in java.util.arraylist."

I'm writing an application to make a seating chart based on excel data, and I have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error when adding elements to an ArrayList of strings. I get that this is caused by calling an index that is outside of the ArrayList's range, but *why* is it out of the range?

The code:

```
public static void breakIfTwo(ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> firstShowStudents, boolean multipleNeeded) {
    ArrayList<HSSFCell> list;
    list = firstShowStudents.get(0);
    ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();
    temporary.add(list.get(4).getStringCellValue());

    for (int i = 1; i < firstShowStudents.size(); i++) {
        list = firstShowStudents.get(i);
        temporary.add(list.get(4).getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: As the exception message implies, you do not have 5 `HSSFCell` objects in your `ArrayList<HSSFCell>`

Comment: The size of the ArrayList<HSSFCell> is 0,1,2,3,4, however. There are [five](https://i.imgur.com/LVAB0dZ.png) elements to it, so I don't see the reason for this error.

Comment: So you say, but the message is quite clear about why it's complaining. Can you try to output `list.size()` in your loop?

Comment: Adding a `System.out.println(list.size());` before the for loop returns [5](https://i.imgur.com/X5fz2C5.png).

Comment: Also, before the loop when you are trying to add the first time

Comment: The exception comes in the addition in the loop, the first one works correctly.

Comment: Ok, then also print it inside your loop. One of the other lists may be smaller than 5

Comment: Ah, thank you. There was a [small inconsistency](https://i.imgur.com/dWIOzg5.png) in the database I was given. It's all good now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's out of range because Java is 0 indexed. In other words an array with a length of 4 is indexed as:

0, 1,2,3.

So 4 is greater than the max index of 3.

Excel, on the other hand, is 1 indexed, meaning that an array with a length of 4 is indexed as: 
1,2,3,4.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but `firstShowStudents` is an ArrayList of almost 9000 elements. `list`'s length based on `firstShowStudents` is also 5, so 4 is a call to the last element, not out of range.

Also, do you have any idea what "653 is not a valid line number in java.util.arraylist." means?

Comment: how about: temporary.add(list.get(list.size - 1).getStringCellValue());

Answer (score 0):

if you put return integer.Max then change
this with arraylist.size();